# Redirect to a local webpage created dynamically in www Wamp folder

Tags: php, file, redirect, wamp, html

I use the PHP code above to create a local page using Wamp in the www folder and I'd like to redirect to this page but the redirection with header doesn't work.

I get the message :

The page isn't redirecting properly.

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies

Does someone know how to do this ?

my code :

```
    $myFileName_with_no_lower_case = 'website_name'.$job.$ville;
    $myFileName = strtolower($myFileName_with_no_lower_case);
    $myFileHandle = fopen($myFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $file_content = file_get_contents('./file_with_content_i_want_to_paste.php');
    fwrite($myFileHandle,$file_content);
    fclose($myFileHandle);
    // eveything works fine until now
    header("Location:".$myFileName);
```

Comment: @Pekka You're right, thanks ! But now I got another problem (related so I won't change post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works now :

```
    $myFileName_with_no_lower_case = $job.$ville;
    $myFileName = strtolower($myFileName_with_no_lower_case);
    $myFileHandle = fopen($myFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $file_content = file_get_contents('./formulaire_artisans.php');
    fwrite($myFileHandle,$file_content);
    fclose($myFileHandle);
    header("Location:".$myFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your solution, one of my faverite functions in my toolbox :)

```
//==== Redirect... Try PHP header redirect, then Java redirect, then try http redirect.:
function redirect($url)
{
        if (!headers_sent())
        { //If headers not sent yet... then do php redirect
                header('Location: ' . $url);
                exit;
        } else
        { //If headers are sent... do java redirect... if java disabled, do html redirect.
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                echo 'window.location.href="' . $url . '";';
                echo '</script>';
                echo '<noscript>';
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=' . $url . '" />';
                echo '</noscript>';
                exit;
        }
} //==== End -- Redirect
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get the same message as usual.

Comment: The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies

Comment: use if(file_exists($myFileName)){ header here } else { echo 'file not exists'; } to make sure your file is certainly there.
Try also accessing the file from the address bar to make sure the file can be accessed via web ( shoudn't be the issue sicne u r on wamp )

Comment: oh that annoying error... you are redirecting to the same page.. an infinite loop. if you need to redirect to the same file do a special GET over the redirect so you won't get redirected after a redirect

Comment: I've checked on the folder and the file exists. When I try to access it with the address bar I get the same message.

Comment: you are redirecting to the same file :/ make some validation, the problem is not from the redirect function or the header redirect you made.